# 2 NIC and access to diffrent lan

Tags: networking, routing, local-area-network

Sorry for my English.

I have problem with configuration of static routes. My LAN looks like:

```
Router A - 192.168.1.1 | Router B - 10.0.0.1
```

Connected to :
Server Windows Server 2019

```
 Nic1 192.168.10:Gateway 192.168.1.10 | Nic2: Virtual Switch 10.0.0.4 Mask 255.255.0.0 GW:empty
```

Now I need to create static route from PC (192.168.1.150) through Server (192.168.1.10) to VM (10.0.0.6) on virtual switch 10.0.0.4

I can't connect via RJ45 these two routers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this 2 ways, you can create a static route in Router 1 so that all traffic destined to 10.0.0.0/16 gets routed to 192.168.1.10, or if you only want PC to access the 10.0.0.0/16 network then you can try this command (for Windows) in an elevated prompt:

route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.10

Comment: thanks I need only 1 pc  to acces into this 10.0.0. lan but could you explane me how create it on router - tplink. Go into static routes and there I have

Destination network | Mask  |Gateway
So this should lokk like 
destination 10.0.0.0
mask 255.255.255.255
and gateway 192.168.1.10???

Comment: The mask should be 255.255.0.0 based on your original post, the destination and gateway are correct.